# Show icon only on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that contains a column with an icon. I want the icons to be hidden by default, and only appear on hover.

**HTML code:**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Connecting Airport</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th>Report</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>JFK</td>
    <td>CPH</td>
    <td>ARN</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" title="Report outdated information" style="color:#da5450;"></i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SFO</td>
    <td>EWR</td>
    <td>ORD</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" title="Report outdated information" style="color:#da5450;"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Minimal Working Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bce9a257/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use javascript for this. Just a few lines of css will do:

```
i.fa {
  display: none;
}
td:hover i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bce9a257/3/

If you want the icons to show on hover of a row in stead of a cell, you could do that like this:

```
i.fa {
  display: none;
}
tr:hover i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**update:**
Obviously you'll need to make that selector a bit more specific to only target the icons in your table. You could for example add an id to your table like `flights` and change those selectors to `#flights i.fa` (and `#flights tr:hover i.fa`)

Comment: always better to rely on css rather than js when possible

Comment: only issue with this solution is that it will affect all other icons on the page

Comment: @kexxcream Not really an issue, just a matter of making the selector a bit more specific. Have a look at the update.